# How to solve three simultaneous equations on Mathematica to get N in terms of X,Y and Z?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a system with 3 equations 3 unknowns. My code is following

X = A1*S + N1

Y = A2*S + N1

Z = N1^2 + A1*N1*S + A2*N1*S + 2*A1*A2*S^2

[image]

Comment: `eqn = {X == A1 S + N1, Y == A2 S + N1, 
  Z == 2 A1 A2 S^2 + A1 N1 S + A2 N1 S + N1^2}` and `Solve[Eliminate[Most@eqn, S], N1] // FullSimplify`

Comment: Solve[Eliminate[Most@eqn, S], N1] // FullSimplify shows no result @chris

Comment: @chris Solve[Eliminate[Most@eqn, S], N1] // FullSimplify shows no result

Comment: What are the unknowns you want to solve for? If the unknowns are `S,N1` you might eliminate them and get one resulting equation `Eliminate[eqn, {S, N1}] (*-A1 A2 Y^2 + A1^2 Z - 2 A1 A2 Z + A2^2 Z == 
 A1 A2 X^2 + (A1^2 - 4 A1 A2 + A2^2) X Y*)`  in `X,Y,Z`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann

My unknown is A1, A2, and S and I have to find N in terms of X, Y, and Z 


Code is

 Eliminate[eqn, {S, A1, A2}]"
Solve[-N1^2 + N1 Y + Z == X (-N1 + 2 Y), N1] I got N in terms of X,Y, Z

Comment: Can you add it as an answer I will readily accept it @UlrichNeumann

Comment: @good_omen92 It looks like you want to solve three equations for four  unknownns `A1,A2,S , N1`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann can we solve three equations for 4 unknowns? My solution gives 100% accurate answer, but what is the principle for no of equations and unknowns?

Comment: @ good_omen92 Usually you won't get a unique solution in your case. But examining your equations you might see that only pairs `A1*S, A2*S` occur. Introducing new parameters `A1S, A2S, N1` gives the expected unique solution.

Comment: That is what I was contemplating, thanks for the clarifications. We are on the same page.. 3 equations and three unknowns and four equations 4 unknowns. Is it? @UlrichNeumann

Comment: I would love if you vote me up I need points here for questions as my research require Mathematica's knowledge and here in my dept no one knows it @UlrichNeumann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the solution of an underdetermined equation system.

```
eqn = {X == A1 S + N1, Y == A2 S + N1,    Z == 2 A1 A2 S^2 + A1 N1 S + A2 N1 S + N1^2}
sol=Solve[eqn, {A1, A2, S, N1} ];

N1/.sol 
(*{1/2 (X + Y - Sqrt[X^2 - 6 X Y + Y^2 + 4 Z]), 
1/2 (X + Y + Sqrt[X^2 - 6 X Y + Y^2 + 4 Z])}*)
```